Don't automatically convert answers to comments
It appears the system will automatically convert every short answer containing a link, into a comment.  This is bad design.  I wrote a short answer that is self-contained and perfectly acceptable as an answer.  This answer should not have been auto-converted to a comment; I am knowledgeable about the Stack Exchange platform and know what is and isn't appropriate for a comment and an answer, and the system should not override my deliberate choice.  In my case, I know that even though my answer is short, it is still valuable and more appropriate as an answer than as a comment.  My answer is short and does contain a link but is not a link-only answer.  The platform should not force me to do something that I know is wrong.
I suggest this auto-convert-to-comment feature should be disabled for people with > 1K reputation (or should only raise a flag for moderator attention but not automatically do the conversion), and should be disabled if the link points to a page on another Stack Exchange site.
Also, I suggest that rather than converting to a comment, the system should provide a warning message and provide an opportunity to add to the answer before converting to a comment.
See also:

Answers automatically converted to comments — a few suggestions
(A by @LightnessRacesinOrbit) Answer appears automatically converted as a comment
(A by @DeadMG) Answer appears automatically converted as a comment
Save me from "trivial answer converted to comment" please!
My answer to a question keeps being posted as comment

Before closing this as a duplicate of Answer appears automatically converted as a comment, please consider that I have made a specific request that was not listed there, and that I have provided context that is not listed there.

Please see High-rep users should be exempt from answer-to-comment autoconversion as well - is that request close enough for you? It is for a smaller case than what you propose (10k+ rep) and doesn't have the warning message part.

Some examples might help. I’m having a hard time thinking of Q&As where this change would do more good than harm.

It also allows bypassing comment locks on questions.

I think enough time has passed since High-rep users should be exempt from answer-to-comment autoconversion that it makes sense to have the conversation again; 11 years is quite a long time.
